# SQL text LIKE doesn't always work

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, full-text-search, sql-like

I'm comparing text values in the same table and same column in SQL Server 2008, but the results are sometimes incorrect. Possibly relevant column info:

```
Data type: text  
Full Text: True  
Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Out of 100 actual matches I only get 62. I have compared field values that are not picked up by LIKE in some comparison tools and they are 100% same, no additional spaces, line breaks etc.

Any idea why text LIKE doesn't always work?

SQL:

```
SELECT a.text as one, b.text as two
  FROM [Db].[dbo].[Table] a join
  [Db].[dbo].[Table] b on
  a.text LIKE b.text
```

Comment: We'll need examples, at the very least of the things you think should be matching but aren't, and the pattern you're using.

Comment: Show us the query you're using (and the data it operates against)! We can't read neither your mind nor your screen ...

Comment: *Any idea why text LIKE doesn't always work?* Same reason the code I write isn't always bug free. The compiler is broke.

Comment: The results *are* correct. The query is wrong.

Comment: Do you get same result if you use = instead of LIKE?

Comment: Post a sample of two identical values that did not match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following two examples show `LIKE` working exactly as expected. I suspect the reason you say "`LIKE` doesn't always work" is because you don't know how `LIKE` works.

Here's an example where one match should occur:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable
(
  [Text] TEXT
);

INSERT INTO #tmpTable VALUES ('Hello');

SELECT *
  FROM #tmpTable tmpTable1
       INNER JOIN #tmpTable tmpTable2
         ON tmpTable1.[Text] LIKE tmpTable2.[Text];

DROP TABLE #tmpTable;
```

"`Hello` is like `Hello`," you say.

Here's a match where no matches should occur:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable
(
  [Text] TEXT
);

INSERT INTO #tmpTable VALUES ('[h]');

SELECT *
  FROM #tmpTable tmpTable1
       INNER JOIN #tmpTable tmpTable2
         ON tmpTable1.[Text] LIKE tmpTable2.[Text];

DROP TABLE #tmpTable;
```

"But `[h]` *is* like `[h]`," you say.

`LIKE` is not the equality operator, it has a special syntax for searching for single characters, ranges of characters and variable numbers of characters. If you happen to feed it text in a column that uses that special syntax (intentionally or not), it will treat the special syntax as character matching instructions, not as literal text.